# How to remove and uninstall AMPPS completely on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, localserver, ampps

I used ampps, but I faced a lot of problems, so I decided to remove it, so i want to remove t cleanly and completly  I have Ubuntu 18.

I tried:

```
sudo apt purge ampps*
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ampps*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ampps*'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ampps*'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't uninstall `ampps` using `apt` because it is installed using the `Ampps-<version>-<arch>.run` script. According to [ampps wiki](https://www.ampps.com/wiki/Installing_AMPPS_on_Linux) : *AMPPS is installed on fixed path `/usr/local/ampps`.*

To uninstall ampps:

```
sudo pkill ampps
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/ampps
```